# Sublime text 3 character offset highlighting by numeral range

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way/plugin in sublime text 3 for highlighting multiple character offset ranges? The ideal desired functionality would be something like this: given a range of character offsets (e.g. 200-400, 5000-5300, 6400-6450) highlight the corresponding ranges.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Do you just want to highlight whenever there is a number, a hyphen, and another number?

Comment: No, I want to be able to enter some character ranges and the editor highlights that ranges for me.
for example by entering 200-400 in a document with length 1000, I want to be able to see the characters from position 200 to 400 highlighted.

Comment: OK, I see. Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: One more question - will you be just entering a single offset at a time, or multiple ones separated by commas?

Comment: The ideal is multiple offsets.

Comment: That's fine, my solution handles multiple offsets, as long as they're comma-separated. I haven't tested putting in spaces - it should work with them, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with a `WindowCommand` plugin. Go to **`Tools -> New Plugin...`** and replace the contents with the following:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class SelectRegionCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def highlight_region(self, regions):
        region_list = []
        if "," in regions:
            for region in regions.split(","):
                region_list.append(tuple(region.split("-")))
        else:
            region_list.append(tuple(regions.split("-")))

        view = self.window.active_view()
        view.show(int(region_list[0][0]))

        for region in region_list:
            begin = int(region[0])
            end = int(region[1])
            to_highlight = sublime.Region(begin, end)
            view.sel().add(to_highlight)

    def run(self):
        message = "Enter offset range(s) to select, separated by commas:"
        default = "0-100"
        self.window.show_input_panel(message, default, self.highlight_region, None, None)
```

Save the file as `Packages/User/select_region.py` (it should open that directory automatically), where `Packages` is the directory opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**.

Next, create a custom key binding to trigger the plugin. Open **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** and add the following line:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "select_region" }
```

If the file is empty, surround the key binding with square brackets `[ ]`. Save the file, and you're all set. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> will bring up an input panel at the bottom of the window where you can enter the character offsets. Please don't include any spaces, so your input should look like the following:

[image]

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the regions you entered will be selected:

[image]

**EDIT**

I altered the code slightly so that the view scrolls to the beginning of the first region entered (it should be centered on the screen). If you don't want that functionality for some reason, just comment out the `view.show(int(region_list[0][0]))` line (line 14).

Comment: is there a line or two that can be added to jump to the first index that is highlighted in the file too?